# Can I get the ID of my sidekiq worker inside the worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging, sidekiq

In sidekiq's log file, I can see IDs of workers, like this:

```
2013-08-28T10:19:03Z 8911 TID-osy5fnl1o MyWorker JID-262996c2737e7a5ec5c71674 INFO: start
2013-08-28T10:19:03Z 8911 TID-ptes4 MyWorker JID-6830e08b5da72b360d4d1ae2 INFO: start
2013-08-28T10:19:03Z 8911 TID-povog MyWorker JID-2d31755b001ecd02fe1abc09 INFO: done: 22.52 sec
2013-08-28T10:19:04Z 8911 TID-povog MyWorker JID-df52f500a3ba27e18b2ba313 INFO: start
```

Inside the body of my worker's @perform@ method, I'd like to get that ID. If not possible, what would be the best strategy to get a unique ID for that worker, taking into consideration that there are multiple concurrent workers of the same class?

I need this for help in processing log files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can access the job id using the jid accessor method and the thread id using the Thread.current method. Like this:

```
logger.info "JID #{jid} - TID #{Thread.current.object_id.to_s(36)}"
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work if you delayed an activerecord model method.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using `ActiveJob` you get get it with `self.job_id` (or `@job_id`).